# Can Xamarin.iOS (14.14.2.5) used with Xcode(11.3.1)?

Tags: ios, xcode

Can someone help me? I update my vs and now xamarin.iOS version is 14.14.2.5 and Xcode version 11.3.1 (unable to upgrade xcode anymore). Now I faced the this error

Error MT4162: The type 'UIKit.UISplitViewControllerColumn' (used as a return type in UIKit.UISplitViewController/_UISplitViewControllerDelegate.GetTopColumnForCollapsing) is not available in iOS 13.2 (it was introduced in iOS 14.0). Please build with a newer iOS SDK (usually done by using the most recent version of Xcode). (MT4162).

I try to change the directory but it says "bad substitution". Is there anyway to solve it?

${xcode11.3.1}/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk: bad substitution

I appreciate for every suggestion. Thank you.